# Можно ли оптимизировать эту хранимую процедуру?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Этой процедура вызывает большие задержки, помогите пожалуйста с её оптимизацией. Работает на SQL 2000 SP 4.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.CalcOst @KodSkl  SMALLINT,
                             @PNT     INTEGER,
                             @Ostatok DECIMAL(18, 5) OUTPUT
AS
     DECLARE @prod DECIMAL(18, 5), @KodPredpr INT;
     SET @Prod = 0;
     SET @Ostatok = ISNULL(
                          (
                              SELECT SUM(CASE DocCaption.VidDoc
                                             WHEN 1
                                             THEN ISNULL(KolF, 0)
                                             WHEN 5
                                             THEN ISNULL(KolF, 0)
                                             WHEN 2
                                             THEN-ISNULL(KolF, 0)
                                             WHEN 3
                                             THEN-ISNULL(KolF, 0)
                                         END)
                              FROM DocString,
                                   DocCaption
                              WHERE DocString.IdDoc = DocCaption.IdDoc
                                    AND DocCaption.KodSkl = @KodSkl
                                    AND DocString.PNT = @PNT
                          ), 0);
     IF EXISTS
     (
         SELECT *
         FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases
         WHERE name = 'Ditron'
     )
         BEGIN
             IF
             (
                 SELECT COUNT(*)
                 FROM tbPredpr
                 WHERE idPredpr = @KodSkl
                       AND idGrPredpr =
                 (
                     SELECT idGrPredpr
                     FROM tbGrPredpr
                     WHERE nameGrPredpr = 'склад-магазин'
                 )
             ) = 1
             AND
             (
                 SELECT COUNT(*)
                 FROM tbNastrSchet
                 WHERE IdPredpr = @KodSkl
             ) = 1
                 BEGIN
                     SET @kodPredpr =
                     (
                         SELECT kodpredpr
                         FROM tbpredpr
                         WHERE idpredpr = @kodskl
                     );
                     SET @prod = ISNULL(
                                       (
                                           SELECT SUM(Ditron.dbo.tbProdaja.Kol)
                                           FROM Ditron.dbo.tbProdaja
                                           WHERE Ditron.dbo.tbProdaja.KodPredpr = @KodPredpr
                                                 AND Ditron.dbo.tbProdaja.PNT = @PNT
                                       ), 0);
                     SET @Ostatok = @Ostatok - @prod;
                 END;
         END;
GO
```

Как я думаю, основная нагрузка идёт на SELECT ... From DocString, DocCaption т. к. почти под миллион строк в DocString и под сто тысяч в DocCaption, но в основном DocString. Что можно сделать?

План выполнения:

```
SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT ON;
GO

SELECT SUM(CASE DocCaption.VidDoc
               WHEN 1
               THEN ISNULL(KolF, 0)
               WHEN 5
               THEN ISNULL(KolF, 0)
               WHEN 2
               THEN-ISNULL(KolF, 0)
               WHEN 3
               THEN-ISNULL(KolF, 0)
           END)
FROM DocString,
     DocCaption
WHERE DocString.IdDoc = DocCaption.IdDoc
      AND DocCaption.KodSkl = 1508
      AND DocString.PNT = 188354;
GO

SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT OFF;
GO
```

Выдал:

```
|--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1004]=If ([Expr1011]=0) then NULL else [Expr1012]))
|--Stream Aggregate(DEFINE:([Expr1011]=COUNT_BIG(If ([DocCaption].[VidDoc]=1) then isnull([DocString].[KolF], 0.00000) else If ([DocCaption].[VidDoc]=5) then isnull([DocString].[KolF], 0.00000) else If ([DocCaption].[VidDoc]=2) then ( -isnull([DocSt
|--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([DocString].[IdDoc]) WITH PREFETCH)
|--Bookmark Lookup(BOOKMARK:([Bmk1000]), OBJECT:([maindatabase].[dbo].[DocString]) WITH PREFETCH)
|--Index Seek(OBJECT:([maindatabase].[dbo].[DocString].[lx1]), SEEK:([DocString].[PNT]=188354) ORDERED FORWARD)
|--Index Seek(OBJECT:([maindatabase].[dbo].[DocCaption].[IX_DocCaption]), SEEK:([DocCaption].[IdDoc]=[DocString].[IdDoc] AND [DocCaption].[KodSkl]=1508) ORDERED FORWARD)
```

Индексы:
DocString 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В lx1 и lx2 тоже самое что и в lx кроме столбца.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67744/discussion-on-question-by-aaa------).

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, `DocCaption.IdDoc` это первичный ключ. Тогда для ускорения конкретно этого запроса, можно создать 2 индекса:

```
таблица: DocCaption
колонки: KodSkl

таблица: DocString
колонки: IdDoc, PNT
```

Если похожих индексов в ваших таблицах нет, то это существенно ускорит хранимую процедуру.

Comment: Я посмотрел и индексы там есть.